# The outset of the edge of cipher

Tags: cipher, story, reverse-puzzling

<sub>This is an entry into the [16<sup>th</sup> Fortnightly Challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5509/fortnightly-topic-challenge-16-reverse-puzzling) : [reverse-puzzling](/questions/tagged/reverse-puzzling)</sub>

---

> Person 1: ***Look at the paper.***
>
> Person 2: *Yes, I see, I see, but I don't know what cipher this is.*
>
> Person 1: ***Okay, let me give you a hint: The outset of airplane becomes the edge of airspace.***
>
> Person 2: *What does that even mean?*
>
> Person 1: ***And the opposite.***
>
> Person 2: *What opposite?*
>
> Person 1: ***The outset of backyard is outset.***
>
> Person 2: *What?*
>
> Person 1: ***And the opposite.***
>
> Person 2: *Seriously, what does that mean?*
>
> Person 1: ***The outset of car is the edge of plane.***
>
> Person 2: *I have no idea what this means.*
>
> Person 1: ***Remember, and the opposite is true, too!***
>
> Person 2: *Okay, only now did I get it. I know what cipher this is.*

Sadly, you do not have the previously mentioned paper. Can you find what cipher this is?

Comment: Well, ROT-13 *kinda* works for the last example, but not really for the others :(

Comment: Not yet, I must be missing something obvious... But I might give it another try soon because of the bounty (if no one else solved it by then) :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Lukas Rotter in comments, this could be something to do with

> the simple [ROT13](http://rot13.com/) cipher.

Specifically, it could work as follows.

> "Outset" and "edge" both refer to the initial letter of a word, while "[X] is [Y]" means that the transformed/enciphered version of X is Y and "[X] becomes [Y]" means that the transformed/enciphered version of X *becomes* Y when the cipher is applied *again*.

*The outset of airplane becomes the edge of airspace.*

> The enciphered version of **A**(irplane) is N, which becomes **A**(irspace) again upon re-enciphering.

*The outset of backyard is outset.*

> The enciphered version of **B**(ackyard) is **O**(utset).

*The outset of car is the edge of plane.*

> The enciphered version of **C**(ar) is **P**(lane).

*And the opposite!*

> Unlike most things in life, the ROT13 cipher is self-reversing: if you do it twice, you get back to where you started. So C enciphering to P, for instance, means that P enciphers to C.

Comment: Damn it, I thought that edge was supposed to be the first *and* last x letters from the word, especially considering that `car` becomes `pne` when ROT-13-ing. Many others and I really missed the obvious, since OP also referred to the first letter of a sentence as *"margin"* in another puzzle. :P

Comment: Congrats, rand al'thor!

@LukasRotter, hopefully you'll have better luck next time!